# Применение унарного минуса к беззнаковым величинам в C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

В стандарте языка неоднократно упоминается, что операции с беззнаковыми целыми выполняются по модулю `2^n`, где `n` - количество бит, участвующих в представлении значения беззнакового целого.

Пусть есть такой код:

```
    unsigned char a = 1;
    a = -a;
```

И, пусть `unsigned char` восьмибитный, а `int` шестнадцатибитный.

Я уже было подумал, что выражение `-a` либо сразу преобразуется в значение типа `unsigned char`, равное `255`; либо `a` расширится до `int`, затем этот `int` примет значение `-1` и, наконец, `-1` преобразуется в значение типа `unsigned char`, равное `255`. Однако, как оказалось, в стандарте указан особый, довольно странный способ вычисления унарного минуса для беззнаковых величин.

Вот цитата пункта 8.3.1/8 из [этого](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) документа:

> The operand of the unary - operator shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type and the result is the negation of its operand. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands. The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from `2^n`, where `n` is the number of bits in the **promoted** operand. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

Если я правильно понял написанное, то значение выражения `-a` в приведённом выше примере равняется величине `2^n - 1`, где `n` равно количеству бит в **расширенном** операнде. Т.е. `2^n - 1 == 2^16 - 1 == 65536 - 1 == 65535`. Но данное значение не может быть представлено в шестнадцатибитном `int`, а значит попытка вычислить `-a` приводит к неопределённому поведению.

Вопрос состоит в следующем: может ли унарный минус "работать" так, как написано выше? И если да, то почему стандарт определяет такое странное поведение унарного минуса для беззнаковых величин?

---

Странно ещё то, что если написать так:

```
    unsigned char a = 1;
    a = 0 - a;
```

то это вроде как не может привести к неопределённому поведению. Так как `0` имеет тип `int`, переменная `a` расширится до `int`, вычислится разность `0-1`, и получившееся в результате значение типа `int` благополучно усечётся по модулю `256` до значения `255`.

Comment: Может, если это unsigned int

Comment: Вы не могли бы уточнить к какого рода неопределённому поведению приводит вычисление `-a` беззнакового типа?
Вероятно, все вычисления в документе касаются представления целого в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дополнительный_код). То есть `N` здесь равно 8 для вашего случая - это бит за пределами `char`: `2^8 = 256`. Результат вычисления не требует дополнительной памяти, так как после вычитания этот дополнительный бит отбрасывается и для `a=1` получаем `255`, а для `0` - `0`

Comment: @mrNAE, вычисление `-a`, приводит к попытке поместить значение 65535 в шестнадцатибитный `int`, и это значение не помещается в диапазон допустимых значений этого типа. А такая ситуация и есть неопределённое поведение, согласно пункту 8/4.

Comment: @wololo, ваши опасения понятны, но как я уже написал выше, дополнительные байты не создаются, а дополнительный бит  - виртуальный. Это лишь подсказка компиляторам как можно реализовать вычисление унарного минуса.

До кучи, чтобы ничего больше не беспокоило: при попытке записать что-то в `unsigned char` будет взят остаток от деления на 256.
Можете проверить на таком примере `int b = 0; char &a = *(char*)&b; a = 1024;` обе переменные останутся нулями лишних байт не будет.

По поводу расширенного операнда, тут всё же речь идёт о дополнении числа (виртуальным) старшим битом (не байтом).

Comment: @mrNAE, В рамках того документа, ссылку на который я оставил в своём вопросе, под термином "Integral promotion" понимается не дополнении числа одним единственным (и притом виртуальным) битом, а вполне конкретное преобразование типа `unsigned char` к типу `int`. Я понимаю, что на практике компилятор вовсе не обязан преобразовывать один тип к другому, и вообще он может как-нибудь по хитрому всё это дело вычислять. Главное, чтобы эффект от всех его вычислений был таким, _как если бы_ он делал так, как написано в стандарте, а стандарт допускает(?) довольно странный результат вычислений.

Comment: Допускает, наверное, потому что в другом стандарте (ISO/IEC 14882-2003 ([взято отсюда](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/INT02-CPP.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules))) пишут по этому поводу -- ` [Note: In a two's
complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there
is no truncation).]`

Comment: @avp, это замечание относится к тексту о преобразовании некоторого целого к беззнаковому целому: "If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo `2^n` where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).". Причём при преобразовании к некоторому беззнаковому, `n` - это кол-во бит в этом беззнаковом. Но в унарном минусе `n` - это почему-то кол-во бит в расширенном операнде, что странно.

Comment: Не до конца понимаю, что вас реально беспокоит. Как именно будет работать в случае `uint64_t` на 64-bit компе?

Comment: @avp, меня беспокоит две вещи: 1) допускает ли стандарт undefined behavior при применении унарного минуса к беззнаковому целому, и если да, то 2) почему `-a` может привести к undefined behavior, а `0-a` нет?

Comment: Тут со мной постоянно спорят, но тем не менее не перестаю считать, что UB для целочисленной арифметики вещь надуманная (более резко -- полный бред). Да, некоторые компы *иногда* (на самом деле *очень редко*) считают не так, как другие. Вот и проверяйте практически, как ваши (для которых программу отлаживаете) это делают (ну, дальше, наверное configure + ifdef)

Comment: 0 имеет тип int, а значит результат `0 - a` тоже имеет тип int, никакого переполнения нет. Если написать `unsigned(0) - a` - скорее всего это будет неопределённым поведением (по крайней мере, я много раз встречал утверждение, что переполнение в любую сторону является UB, но но не уверен, что говорит стандарт на этот счет). А `-a`, вероятно, ведёт себя так для того, что бы unsigned(-1)  равнялся ffff... соответствующей разрядности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слова про 2<sup>n</sup> относятся только к unsigned типам (арифметика по модулю `max() + 1` — результат всегда определён). Эти слова не относятся к int типу.

Если все значения `unsigned char` типа помещаются в `int` (часто бывает), то (C++ n4659 §7.6.1):

```
-(unsigned char)1 = (integer promotion, likely) = -(int)1 = (int)-1
```

Если не помещаются, то:

```
-(unsigned char)1 = (integer promotion, rare) = -(unsigned int)1 
    = (unsigned int)2**n-1 = (by definition) = (unsigned int)UINT_MAX
```

где `n` это кол-во бит для значений (value bits — могут отличаться от `sizeof * CHAR_BIT`, если есть padding bits — C n1570 §6.2.6.2.1).

То есть тип `-a`  выражения равен int или unsigned int. Чтобы присвоить назад в `a` необходимо (возможно сужающее преобразование) в unsigned char:

```
(int)-1 = (UCHAR_MAX + 1) - 1 = (unsigned char)UCHAR_MAX
```

или:

```
(unsigned int)UINT_MAX = UINT_MAX % (UCHAR_MAX + 1) = (unsigned char)UCHAR_MAX
```

то есть значение [всегда получается в этом случае 2<sup>CHAR_BIT</sup>-1](https://ideone.com/c2p2go):

```
a == std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()
```

Answer (score 1):

Определимся с понятиями в [документе](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

п. **6.10**:

> A *prvalue* is an expression whose evaluation initializes an object or a bit-field, or computes the value of
>   the operand of an operator, as specified by the context in which it appears

п. **7.6 Integral promotions**

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion
>   rank (7.15) is less than the rank of int **can be converted** to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the
>   values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int

Суть всего этого в том, что для сохранения всего диапазона значений после вычисления, например унарного минуса, **может** применяться обобщающее расширение типа до `int`. Необходимость этого действия (**promoted operand**) определяется контекстом.

В коде

```
unsigned char a = 10;
unsigned char b = -a;
```

обобщающее расширение можно не применять, так как и результат и место его хранения - один байт, дополнительного места для хранения не требуется. Здесь `N=8`, `2^8=256`, `256-10=246`. А вот здесь

```
int c = -a;
```

тип для сохранения результата `int`, поэтому `N=32`, `2^32-10=-10` (в дополнительном коде).

В **8.3.1 Unary operators** п.8 утверждается, что величина `N` должна быть взята не от исходного типа, а от конечного, который, в частности, может быть обобщающим - всё исходя из контекста.

А грабли лежат совсем рядом:

**7.8 Integral conversions**

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type;
>   otherwise, the **value is implementation-defined**.

**7.9 Floating-point conversions**

> A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of another floating-point type. If the
>   source value can be exactly represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is that exact
>   representation. If the source value is between two adjacent destination values, the result of the conversion is
>   an **implementation-defined** choice of either of those values. Otherwise, the **behavior is undefined**

Поэтому предупреждения компилятора о попытке сравнить знаковый тип с беззнаковым или о неявных преобразованиях с понижением размерности пренебрегать не стоит.

Comment: Про *Floating-point* тут, имхо, ни к чему.

Comment: Пожалуй, про грабли в целом ни к чему. Так, до кучи - всё что связано с  обобщением типа и где искать проблемы. Главное не выдумывать лишние сложности.